# Image maps with curves

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create many image maps with custom edges, especially curved ones. The only options I could find were polygons with straight edges. While it's possible to simulate curves with zillions of points, the user will be given the option to zoom the images and perfect curves are crucial.

Isn't there a way of using, say, bezier curves on these image maps? If at all possible, I don't want to use SVG objects since it seems to be unnecessarily complex (although, obviously, I might be wrong).

Comment: Can you post an example image?

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/VqpqenR.png) is a _really_ simple example compared to what I want to achieve, but it gives an idea. Each color corresponds to an interactive area. The curves in the real image are much crazier than these.

Answer (score 1):

imagemaps are an ancient html feature and back at that time, nobody considered bezier curves. There is one (rarely used) feature of image maps that could be your solution though: [server-side image maps](http://www.w3.org/WAI/wcag-curric/sam19-0.htm).

They do work a bit differently: Instead of defining different urls for specific areas, you define one url for the entire map, and the corrdinates, where the user clicks are appended to that url. The [above link](http://www.w3.org/WAI/wcag-curric/sam19-0.htm) also gives you an example how you can try it.

e.g. if you have such an image map, that links to http://foo.com/target and you click somewhere (say at pixel coords 25/27), then the user http://foo.com/target?25,27

with that in place, you could now decide on the server side, where the user has clicked. (and there you could use more complex polygons with beziérs to determine the area)

Comment: Lovely answer! You could maybe describe the type/format of response and server-side handling.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you've stated SVG is unnecessarily complex, but really, it isn't, *and* it has built-in support for bezier curves, which maps don't.

Use the `<path>` SVG-element to create bezier curves, check out [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves):

> So we'll start with the slightly more complex Bezier curve: the cubic one, C. Cubic Beziers take in two control points for each point. As such, you have to specify three sets of coordinates when you want to create a cubic Bezier

```
C x1 y1, x2 y2, x y (or c dx1 dy1, dx2 dy2, dx dy)
```

> The last set of coordinates here `(x,y)` are where you want the line to end. The other two are control points. `(x1,y1)` is the control point for the start of your curve, and `(x2,y2)` for the end point of your curve. If you are familiar with algebra or calculus, the control points essentially describe the slope of your line starting at each point. The Bezier function then creates a smooth curve that transfers you from the slope you established at the beginning of your line, to the slope at the other end.

So, to produce a cubic bezier curve in HTML, all you need is the below:

```html
<svg width="190px" height="100px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M50 50 C 25 75, 125 75, 100 50" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
</svg>
```

In javascript, you could set such a curve using JS similar to the following:

```js
var svg = document.getElementById('svgl');

var path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
path.setAttributeNS(null, 'd', 'M10 10 C 20 20, 40 20, 50 10');
path.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'black');
path.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'transparent');

svg.appendChild(path);
```

```html
<svg id="svgl" width="190px" height="100px" version="1.1" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
</svg>
```

Basically, all you need to know about SVG bezier curves, the "complex" bit, is how your values affect the control points:

In a `<path>` element, really, the only thing which matters is the `d` attribute, which decides what the path will construct.

For a bezier curve, the path must have

```
C x1 y1, x2 y2, x y
```

somewhere within it. In my above examples, all `Mx y` does is tell the path where to start from.

In

```
C x1 y1, x2 y2, x y
```

each pair of x/y coordinates controls either the end of the curve (as in `x y`), or, (as in `x1 y1`, `x2 y2`) control points.

Here's a handy diagram:

[image: M600,500 C600,350 900,650 900,500]

You can see how the inputs affect the final shape of the bezier curve,

[image: Mx,y Cx1,y1 x2,y2 x3,y3]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation!  

However, the "complex bit" I refer to is that, as far as I know, SVGs aren't that straightforward in terms of events (hovering, clicking, etc.) - there seem to be cross-domain issues when you try to handle SVG objects (the project will be embeddable); also, I've found issues regarding styling and link positioning. Again, I might just be wrong and overcomplicating things.

Comment: @EdJr Really? I made an SVG project not too recently ([it's actually on github; my only thing on github](https://github.com/theonlygusti/JustTank)) and hovering, clicking, mouseovers, etc. work exactly the same as any other events, on any other "normal" element. But yeah, I see what you mean ;)

Answer (score -1):

To make a circle in CSS, the what you need to do is to change the border radius to 50%;

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px; 
}
```

So without getting overly detailed, the border-radius would be the best place to begin with playing with curved edges.

Additionally this link through css tricks may be another great starting point. 
https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/